# App Stopped Working On setImageResource of CircleImageView

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I have to show some images dynamically using java code in app horizontally. I can do this using simple `ImageView`. But using [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) by "hdodenhof". I am able to use only static image hardcoded in the XML file. I want the source to be dynamically selected from my java code. I have tried some option. But the app seems to stop working. Is there anything I can do? Thank you in advance.

Here is my `DisplayMessageActivity.java` file

```
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

LinearLayout pages=findViewById(R.id.pages);
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);

for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,pages,false);
    CircleImageView circleImageView=findViewById(R.id.circleimage);
    circleImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
    pages.addView(view);
}
```

And the `item.xml` file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/circleimage"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#00000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the `activity_display_message.xml` file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The application shows the following message in the dialog and the app crashes.

> Testingapp stopped working

Comment: hello ! use setImageDrawable() of CircleImageview instead of setImageResource()

Comment: try to load the image using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or any other image loader library.

Comment: I have also tried setimagedrawable but it still stops working @nice

Comment: Can you explain about glide? I am new to android.

Comment: @Dipto Roy Show us your error messages

Comment: @VivekSingh there is no error message .It only stops when the app seems to run.

Comment: Change _CircleImageView circleImageView=findViewById(R.id.circleimage);_ to             _CircleImageView circleImageView=view.findViewById(R.id.circleimage);_

Comment: @DiptoRoy I meant your logcat errors. There must be some exceptions if the app crashes in runtime

Comment: Thank you @Piyush I am trying your approach

Comment: @DiptoRoy what is the image size you're trying to load?

Comment: Image size is 179KB @Rahul

Comment: I am trying to show the error here @Vivek

Comment: @piyush thank you for you solution also.It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are getting a null pointer exception and that's why the application is crashing. Looks like your activity set the content view to the `activity_display_message.xml` layout in your `setContentView` in your `onCreate` function. Hence the `findViewById` will only find the references from that layout only.

The `CircleImageView` is defined in a different layout which is not inflated in your activity and hence while you are doing `findViewById(R.id.circleimage);` - you are getting a null pointer exception as the instruction did not find the view that you are looking for.

You need to take the layout reference of your `CircleImageView` from the view that you have inflated inside your for loop. I think the following should solve your problem.

```
CircleImageView circleImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.circleimage);
```

Comment: Thank you Reaz vai.Now I have understood the error of my code.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Great to know that I could help. You are welcome! :)

Comment: Vai ,I have a small question. How could the instruction found my imageview id when I used only normal ImageView though it was on different layout item.xml?

Comment: It should not. However, I cannot confirm without seeing some code.

Comment: No worries! Happy coding.